# Quickly switch between rems and pixels in a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

I set initial font-size of body to 62.5% so to be equal to 10px. Then I set elements font-size to 1.2rem, 2rem and so on. Everything works fine.

Now I want to set pixels instead of rems for IE8, not to be bothered too much by dealing with its quirks. So, I add a new `ie.styl` file that I conditionally attach if it's IE. Inside it I want to change rems to pixels wherever rems are in original file. My question - is there some good way to do it in automatic manner, like what nib does for browsers-specific prefixed CSS options?

So, as a result, I add something like `font-size units(1.2)` in original file, and it generates two files - `style.css` and `ie.css`, where `font-size: 1.2rem;` will be in first file, and `font-size: 12px;` in the former one?

Comment: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/ and http://csswizardry.com/2011/05/font-sizing-with-rem-could-be-avoided/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do is declare both, IE will use the fallback

```
.font {
   font-size:16px; /* ie fallback */
   font-size:1rem;
}
```